# How to secure my windows phone 8.1 application?

Tags: c#, security, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am a windows phone developer using c# and xaml technologies.
Currently I am creating a banking application for my client and it is targeting for Windows phone 8.1 OS version.

And I am using Windows Phone xaml app template for creating it.

Since It is a banking application I need to get it maximum secured. As I send my Appx file to the bank technical team , They have made concern about the app security. And they had sent me the codes I have wrote for my application by the process of reverse engineering.

What I need to do against ? And in what way we can avoid this type of vulnerabilities? Please suggest me best way to avoid this.

Thanks

Comment: You mean to secure the `.appx` files?

Comment: Couple of ideas: you may think of [code obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)), write some crucial methods in C++ (it should be harder to reverse), remember to secure any sensitive data (strigns and so on), encrypt some data, use PasswordVault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The security of the banking application should not depend on the client code being secret. You should not store any secrets on the client as it is impossible to keep them from an attacker.

Use encrypted communications (https) to talk to the server. Validate the used certificates, authenticate the user and have the server issue an access token with a limited time to live. These are all industry best practices. Don't try to invent your own security measures.

Comment: yeah! right. I have to encrypt string in those files stored in storage folder. We are using the https for communication with server.

Comment: what if someone get in to my code and access my api and encryption code details ?

Comment: If someone gets inside your code and steals the token, they will have the same access as your application has for that specific user. There's just no way you can reliably distinguish between a valid application and a malignant one. So make sure your users only have the permissions they actually need and not more.

Comment: yup. sure. Also please let me know if any future updates on this topic .

Answer (score 2):

I'd say Security by Obscurity isn't really state of the art any longer...

Once your package got submitted to the store, it will be encrypted and it won't be such easy to reverse engineer any longer. You can ask them to decompile a package they downloaded from the store.

Other thing you can do is using an Obfuscator by yourself to make your code harder to reverse engineer.

You have to make sure to encrypt locally stored date (for example using the PasswordVault) and such.

But in the end, you still have to deliver your code to the phone itself and if somebody really want's to work through it, he always can do that. You can just make it harder.

**Update:** I just checked back and the store encryption of install files only holds to be true for XAP (Silverlight) files. Don't have an official state for appx files yet, but will definitely come either.

See details [here](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BnAi5M9CEAA2T0a.png:large).

Comment: Have you got any reference about this package encrypted by the store?

Comment: True... you have to design the app in a way that even if someone has the source code it is secure... this is the only way to do it...

Comment: @Romasz: Just checked. Only for XAP, not yet for appx sadly. :( Updated the answer.

Comment: Moreover, XAP DRM doesn't help much as interlocked unlocked devices can access the application's installation folder where the unprotected assemblies are stored. So, the only true option is to obfuscate the app or use C++ and WinRT.

Comment: @KaiBrummund so my package type is .appx. As in in the provided  link , package is still not encrypted.right ?

Comment: Correct. But as many here said: Security should not depend on the ability to read your code, because with an interop unlocked device, people will still be able to get the code after installation.